# Question Using Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm tasked with showing that if $f$ is continuous on $[1, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$, then there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\sup_{x \in [1, \infty)} |f(x)-p(\frac{1}{x})|<0.001$.

It's clear that by Weierstrass Approximation Thm, we can find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that on any interval $I=[1,r]$, $\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)-p(x)|<0.001$, but I'm not sure how this helps or what I can do to move towards a solution.

I'm really trying to work through this, so I'd appreciate hints or guidance rather than entire proofs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $g(x)=f(1/x).$ We have that $g$ is continous on $[0,1]$ defining $g(0)=a.$ Now, apply the Weierstrass aproximation theorem to $g.$